# Object reference not set to an instance of an object on layout page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an edit form in an edit page.When I come in the page for the first time everything is OK.But after submitting the form I see this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

And in the source error you see this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout ="~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

What is wrong now?!

**Update**

My view codes:

```
@model Portal.Web.CMS.Models.PageViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ویرایش صفحه";
    Layout ="~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h3>صفحه</h3>
<ul class="breadcrumb" style="background-color: white;">
    <li><a href="~/Page">لیست صفحات</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Page", new { url = Model.Url })">@Model.Name</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
    <li class="active">ویرایش صفحه</li>
</ul>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PageId)
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lang)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" dir="ltr">
            @if (Model.Lang.ToString() == "Fa")
            {
                <button type="button" value="2" class="btn">English</button>
                <button type="button" value="1" class="btn active">فارسی</button>
            }
            else
            {
                <button type="button" value="2" class="btn active">English</button>
                <button type="button" value="1" class="btn">فارسی</button>
            }
        </div>
        @Html.Hidden("Lang")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Url)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Url)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Url)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PageContent)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PageContent)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PageContent)
    </div>
    <div id="attachments" class="editor-field">
        <p>
            <button type="button" id="addFile" class="btn btn success">فایل بیشتر</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="files" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="productImages" class="editor-field">
        <p>
            <button type="button" id="addPicture" class="btn btn success">عکس بیشتر</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="images" />
        </p>
    </div>
    if (Model.PageAttachements!=null )
    {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>فایل های ضمیمه</legend>
        <div class="row-fluid show-grid">
            @foreach (var file in Model.PageAttachements)
            {
                <div class="span4 thumbnail">
                    <a href="~/Page/DeleteFile/@file.PageAttachmentId" class="close pull-left" onclick="return confirm('آیا میخواهید مورد فوق را حذف نمایید؟')" >&times;</a>
                    @file.Name
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    }
    if (Model.PageImages.Count > 0)
    {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>تصاویر ضمیمه</legend>
        <div class="row-fluid show-grid">
            @foreach (var image in Model.PageImages)
            {
                <div class="span4 thumbnail">
                    <a href="~/Product/DeleteImage/@image.PageImageId" class="close pull-left" onclick="return confirm('آیا میخواهید مورد فوق را حذف نمایید؟')" >&times;</a>
                    <img src="~/Images/@image.Name" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    }
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="ذخیره" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" />
    </p>
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And the controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var model = Mapper.Map<PageViewModel>(pageApp.GetPageById(id));
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(PageViewModel model)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (model.Lang.ToString() == "Fa")
        result = pageApp.IsRepetitive(model.Url, 1);
    else
        result = pageApp.IsRepetitive(model.Url, 2);
    if (result == true)
    {
        TempData["error"] = "صفحه ای با همین زبان و آدرس وجود دارد.";
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        if (model.PageContent != null)
        {
            var page = Mapper.Map<Page>(model);
            page.UserId = Portal.Web.CMS.Components.SessionContext.GetUserData().UserId;
            page.PageDate = DateTime.Now;
            pageApp.Update(page);
            TempData["success"] = "صفحه با موفقیت تغییر یافت.";
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { url = model.Url });
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["error"] = "انجام نشد.صفحه خالی از مطلب است.";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the rest of your View and applicable Controller code

Comment: Do you Redirect to that view?

Comment: @RoyDictus After editing,no.

Comment: @HamidReza try `return View(model);` instead of `return View();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In these lines:

```
TempData["error"] = "انجام نشد.صفحه خالی از مطلب است.";
return View();
```

You are returning the `Edit` view with no model. Hence you get a NullReferenceException when trying to access your model in your view.

You need to return the appropriate model back to the View:

```
return View(model);
```

**Sidenote:** Since you're using strongly-typed models anyway, you might want to add an `Error` property onto your model instead of using `TempData`.

Comment: Thank you and about your side note,yes.You are right.Ill chang it.Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Because return View(); dose not have Model Object
as you have given in  Edit like return View(model)